# Warranty options a replacement via warranty

Tags: consumer-protection, warranties

Firstly I am based in the UK. I purchased a hedge trimmer back in 2016 which came with a 2 year warranty which became faulty and was replaced under warranty in late 2017.

The replacement is now faulty. I am unable to find any proof paperwork or electronic my only hope would be that the supplier has proof. Does this replacement usually come with the same warranty period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Replacements are provided to honour the warranty period for the original purchase only. Your combined use of the original trimmer and the replacement is now beyond 2 years, so no entitlement to a second replacement even if the first one worked less than 2 years.